# why Ross's solution for average number of uniform random variable needed to get a sum greater than 1 is independent of the type of random variable?

Tags: probability

In Example 7.5j of *Sheldon Ross' A First Course in Probability, fifth edition,* the author gives a solution to the following problem:

> Suppose we have some independent uniform random variable in $[0,1]$. How many of these random variables should we pick until the some of them exceed $1$?

Solution:

1. Let $N(x)$ be the number of uniform $(0,1)$ random variables we must add until their sum exceeds $x$, and $m(x)$ is its expected value. So
   $$m(x) = E\left[N(x)\right]$$
2. We will now derive an equation for $m(x)$ by conditioning on $U_1$ (the first uniform random variable)
   $$m(x) = \int_{0}^1{E\left[N(x)|U_1=y\right]}\,dy$$
3. Here, use the fact that
   $$E[N(x)|U_1=y] =\begin{cases}1, & \text{ if } y>x \\1+m(x-y), & \text{ if } y \le x \end{cases}$$
4. Substituting Equations:
   $$m(x) = 1 + \int_{0}^x{m(x-y)}dy=1 + \int_{0}^x{m(u)}du $$

Differentiating the equation and solving the differential equation, we get $$ m(x)= e^x$$
My  questions:

1. Considering that the differential of $u=x-y$ is $du=-dy$, why there is no negative sign in the integration of the Step 4.
2. The fact that the random variables are uniform does not have any impact on the solution. Therefore, doing the same procedure with any random variable with finite support (in range $[0,1]$) gives the same result, which is counter-intuitive. If you pick number from a RV which tends to give you smaller results in $[0,1]$, you would probably expect to pick more RV until their sum exceeds $1$. Which is not happening here?!! Is it really true?
3. Does this formula work only for $x=1$? If not, why the solution given by wolfram (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformSumDistribution.html) is different from this solution for $x>1$?

Comment: If $x>1$, in step $4$ the bounds of intergration gotta be $0$ to $\min(x,1)$, so the cute $m(x)=e^x$ holds only on $[0,1]$.

Comment: For $x>1$, $m'(x)=m(x)-m(x-1)$ which yields $m(x)=e^x-e^{x-1}(x-1)$ on $(1,2]$. You can continue this piece-wise construction of $m(x)$ one unit interval after another.

Comment: This also shows that $m'(x)$ is discontinuous at $1$ with a drop of $1$ from $e$ to $e-1$.

Comment: @A.S. your piece-wise construction method works perfectly, but i don't understand how you solve that differential equation with delayed argument. For $$m(x)=e^x−e^{x−1}(x−1)$$, the equality $$m′(x)=m(x)−m(x−1)$$ does not hold!!

Comment: Of course it holds. $m(x-1)=e^{x-1}$ for $x\in[1,2]$.

Comment: Just as a simple counterexample to question 2: the answer with independent uniform random variables in $[0,1]$ is $e\approx 2.718$ while the answer with  independent uniform random variables in $[\frac12,1]$ would be $2$

Answer (score 1):

Considering your questions:

1. If we substitute $u=x-y$ then $du=-dy$ but check also the limits of integration: $$\int_{0}^{x}m(x-y)dy=\int_{x}^{0}-m(u)du=\int_{0}^{x}m(u)du$$
2. When you solve the differential equation $$m'(x)=m(x)$$ you find that $$m(x)=e^x+c$$ so you need some initial condition (that depends on the distribution of the random variables, so here is one point where the uniform distribution is used) to determine the constant $c$. Another point where the uniform distribution is used is in $$m(x) = \int_{0}^1{E\left[N(x)|U_1=y\right]}\cdot f_{U_1}(y)\,dy$$ but $U_1(y)=1$ in this interval, so he just wrote 
   $$m(x) = \int_{0}^1{E\left[N(x)|U_1=y\right]}\,dy$$
3. I do not exactly understand this question.

Comment: As it is mentioned in the book m(0)=1 for uniform random variable. I don't see any reason why this might be different for any other random variable. Basically, m(0) tells us how many random variable we need to get a sum greater than 0. So, I guess that would be 1 for any random variable with positive range!

Comment: @Shahbaz Yes, this is correct. But there is also another point where the pdf of $U$ is used, namely when conditioning to find the $m(x)$.

Comment: @Stef Well, that was quit convincing.

Comment: A.S. I know there must be some flaw, but I cannot spot which condition does not hold in this case.

Comment: @Shahbaz Ok, I see that the point $m(x)=e^x+c$ is trivial, since $c=0$ for any non-negative random variable, by your remark, but I will not delete it, since, ok although trivial it is also used there.

Comment: @A.S. Ok, thanks for explaining part 3. If I find the flaw I will edit my answer.

Comment: To be precise, $m(x)=e^x$ on $[0,1]$ only and is strictly less than that outside of it.